# Loading one directive from another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two custom directives, as shown below: `app1` and `app2`. `app2` should be shown only when I click on a specific button in `app1`. What's the best way I can achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
module.directive('app1', function() {
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,controller) {
            var filter = scope.getFilters(attrs.appname);
        },
        templateUrl: '../directives/filter/partials/filter.html' ,
        controller: "filterCtrl"
    };
});

module.module('app2').directive('dmView', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',  
        controller: 'viewController',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {     
            var viewData = scope.getViewData(attrs.appname);
            var options = {
                forceFitColumns: false,
                enableColumnReorder: false
            }
          var grid;
          grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', viewData.data, viewData.columns, options);
          scope.grid = grid;
        },
        templateUrl: '../directives/view/partials/view.html' 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a shared view model (scope) to show or hide app2.

You can set an `ng-show="someModelVar"` attribute on app2. In your init, ensure that someModelVar is null or another falsey value.

In your handling of the button click in app1, set someModelVar to a non-falsey value. You can use a custom attribute on app1 to avoid hard-coding the parent scope variable name in the directive code.

You can define a common parent scope to allow this:

```
<div ng-controller='parentScope'>
  <!-- define someModelVar in parent scope -->
  <div ng-controller='app1Controller'>
    <app1 my-app2-flag-var='someModelVar'>...</app1>
    ...
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='app2Controller' ng-show='someModelVar'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```